# How to correct these c++ errors 'Invalid conversion' and 'no match for operator'

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to read through file that contains series of words and sentences.
Then, needs to Store the unique words and maintain a count of each different word.The words should be ordered by decreasing count and, if there are multiple
words with the same count, alphabetically. (This ordering may be achieved as
the words are read in, partially as the words are read or at the end of all input processing.)In the end, I want to Output the first and last ten words in the sorted list, along with their counts.

How to fix this `const char*` error. I dont know what is wrong in my code or where and what exactly do I have to change:

[Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

[Error] no match for 'operator<=' (operand types are 'WordType' and 'WordType')

```
struct WordType
{
    int word;
    int len, count;
};

const int MaxWords=50000;
char Words[MaxWords*10];
WordType Counters[MaxWords];
int NumWords=0;


bool Compare(WordType &A, WordType &B){
    if(A.count<B.count)return true;
    if(A.count>B.count)return false;
    char w1[50],w2[50];
    strncpy(w1,Words[A.word],A.len);   //Error comes here
    w1[A.len]='\0';
    w2[B.len]='\0';
    strncpy(w2,Words[A.word],B.len);   //Error comes here
    return strcmp(w1,w2) < 0 ;  
}

int partition (int low, int high)
{
    WordType pivot = Counters[high]; 
    int i = (low - 1); 

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
    {
        if (Compare(Counters[j] <= pivot))      //Error comes here
        {
            i++;
            swap(&Words[i], &Words[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&Words[i + 1], &Words[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
      int pi = partition(low, high);
       quickSort(low, pi - 1);
       quickSort(pi + 1, high);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error? `Words[A.word]` is a `char`, while `strncpy` expects 2nd argument to be `const char*`.

Comment: I didnt know that

Comment: I didnt know what was the point of this error

Comment: Now i need to fix this error

Comment: 1) Compilers, nowadays, state exact line of the errors they encounter. 2) To fix the error, one needs to know your intentions with said code. And your intentions, with such a code aren't clear.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am gonna add a bit more explanation which will help, hopefully.

Comment: Except for use of references, this is C, not C++ as it is tagged.

Comment: There is no reason to copy the strings in your compare function.

Answer (score 1):

*(Whatever your intention with the code, I just looked at the 3 bugs)*

This compare function solves the 1st & 2nd compile errors:

```
#include <string>

bool Compare(WordType &A, WordType &B)
{
    if (A.count < B.count)
        return true;

    if (A.count > B.count)
        return false;

    std::string w1{ Words[A.word] }, w2{ Words[B.word] }; // Fix

    return (strcmp(w1.c_str(), w2.c_str()) < 0);
}
```

The compare function gets 2 parameters, so I guess you actually want to call it like:

```
if (Compare(Counters[j], pivot)) // Fix
```

-

Beside that, I prefer to use `std:array` & to initialize variables:

```
#include <array>

struct WordType
{
    int word = 0;
    int len = 0, count = 0;
};

constexpr int MaxWords = 50000;
std::array<char, MaxWords * 10> Words;
std::array<WordType, MaxWords> Counters;

int NumWords = 0;

// & to call in main():
Words.fill('\0');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (Compare(Counters[j] , pivot))
strncpy(w2,(const char *)Words[A.word],B.len); 
strncpy(w2,(const char *)Words[A.word],B.len);
```

This is how your error line should look like